# gzipped file is smaller than Shannon limit?

Tags: algorithm, unix, compression

I have a text file that's 664KB in size (using ls -l). To my understanding, a file cannot be compressed into anything smaller than the [Shannon Source Coding limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) without incurring information loss.
I used a program here to calculate the average shannon entropy of the textfile (4.36) and multiplied it by its number of characters. I get **371KB**.

Then, I used bzip2 which to my understanding is lossless, and found that it compressed the file to **171K**. From what i understand, nothing can be compressed smaller than the shannon limit without losing information, so how can bzip compress a file losslessly that is smaller than it? Am I missing some information as to how the os is encoding the file perhaps?

[The text file I used for this experiment is MIT Classic's The Republic by Plato](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/republic.html).

[The program I used to calculate shannon entropy is this one](https://kennethghartman.com/calculate-file-entropy/). It gave me the same result as another program I used to cross-check it.

Comment: That limit would apply if all you did was entropy code the data byte by byte. But that's not what either of those algorithms do. They also perform various transformations on the data, and encode the results of that. | For example, consider linear sequence of 256 bytes, with values going from 0 to 255. (as in 0,1,2,3,4...,254,255). What' the entropy of that? Now delta code that first (calculate differences between consecutive bytes) - you'll get a 0 followed by a lot of 1s. Now what's the entropy of the transformed data?

Comment: Or, say that we have the same sequence repeated 100 times in a row. Once the first 256 bytes have been encoded, you can deal with the rest by saying "repeat the last 256 bytes 99 times". That's the sort of transformation that LZ based algorithms do.

Comment: To see that in practice, try shuffling the characters in the file at random and measuring the compressed size (several times, even).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that generally we cannot compress better than the Shannon entropy (by assuming no loss), and it is true that all *zip* encoding are lossless.

However, a few points must be considered.

For the Shannon entropy (on the contrary of some kind of logarithm entropy), a statistical model is assumed for the information.

In some particular cases (not totally random, respecting some rules..), it may happen that no statistical model can perfectly handle all the a priori knowledge that we can have.

However, this is not the most important issue here. By looking at the code that you used, it appears that the only statistical information which is considered is the frequency of each character. This implicitly assumes that there is no correlation between the characters.

It is clear that it is a very restrictive assumption, certainly not valid for a text file.

It is clear that your compression algorithm is able to benefit from the correlation between adjacent characters.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the model.

The model used in your calculation is that each byte value has some independent probability. This is called "Order 0", since the probability at each byte location depends on zero preceding bytes.

A more sophisticated model would use information from the preceding bytes to generate a probability distribution for the current byte. bzip2 makes use of the context of other bytes, as do all general-purpose lossless compressors such as gzip and xz.

By the way, [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) has a `-H` or `--huffman` option which does Order 0 compression (Huffman coding only), and will get close to the Order 0 Shannon limit you are computing.